# Customizing task statuses in Airflow (adding my own new status)

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I want to add my own status to the list of task's statuses available out of the box.
Currently, I see in airflow/utils/state.py

```
class TaskInstanceState(str, Enum):

    REMOVED = "removed"  # Task vanished from DAG before it ran
    SCHEDULED = "scheduled"  # Task should run and will be handed to executor soon

    # Set by the task instance itself
    QUEUED = "queued"  # Executor has enqueued the task
    RUNNING = "running"  # Task is executing
    SUCCESS = "success"  # Task completed
    SHUTDOWN = "shutdown"  # External request to shut down (e.g. marked failed when running)
    RESTARTING = "restarting"  # External request to restart (e.g. cleared when running)
    FAILED = "failed"  # Task errored out
    UP_FOR_RETRY = "up_for_retry"  # Task failed but has retries left
    UP_FOR_RESCHEDULE = "up_for_reschedule"  # A waiting `reschedule` sensor
    UPSTREAM_FAILED = "upstream_failed"  # One or more upstream deps failed
    SKIPPED = "skipped"  # Skipped by branching or some other mechanism
    DEFERRED = "deferred"  # Deferrable operator waiting on a trigger
```

Something like

```
MYCUSTOMSTATUS = 'custom'
```

On the top, I want State.MYCUSTOMSTATUS to have its own unique color, so when a task (based on PythonOperator) will be set to to the new status via

```
task_instance.set_state(state=State.MYCUSTOMSTATUS)
```

I can easily distinguish tasks having this status in the graph view.
Can someone guide me how to that (if this is possible at all)?

Comment: could you explain what problem you want to solve?

Comment: I want to have my own status with its own color for tasks based on custom logic, so I can distinguish them visually, e.g. I run a workflow where the tasks identify application component status (an underlying Linux process is up or down). If down, I want the task which ran it being painted with its dedicated color, thus visually I can see it right away. Today I have to raise AirflowFailException, so they are marked in red but I can't know by looking at the graph whether the task is red because  the component it checked is down or because I have some exception during the task execution.

Comment: ok. Maybe I don't understand something. Are these very long-term tasks? Where you will set state and for how long? I mean the scheduler will overwrite your state.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the task duration. I want my custom state being set "permanently". I mean if my task is finished,  I want to set the task's state to my custom state based on some business logic, so the task will stay with my custom state. This is *instead* letting  scheduler setting the state.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer:

> No. This is can't be controlled using the basic settings / options

As I know:

- You can customize color states using [settings.py](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.7.1/howto/customize-ui.html#customizing-state-colours)
- You can customize task colors using [ui_color / ui_fgcolor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.7.1/_api/airflow/models/baseoperator/index.html#airflow.models.baseoperator.BaseOperator.ui_color)

Also you can try to change task states after *failure / success* using [callbacks](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/logging-monitoring/callbacks.html#callbacks). But not sure if this is a good idea.